# Error TS2339: Property ‘u_email_address’ does not exist on type ‘LoginPage’

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I tried to make a login & register page using mysql and php as the backend, but the toast timeout (image 1 below) keep came out yet the data is been saved (image 2 below)

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

There is no error after click on the register button except Timeout alert, but there are few errors like this before the page appear
[image: error]
[image: error]

This is my code in login.page.html

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar color="warning">
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <div class="">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="u_email_address"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="u_password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <br><br><br>
      <ion-button expand="block" class="ion-padding" color="warning" (click)="tryLogin()">Login</ion-button>
  </div>

    <p class="ion-text-center info-1">
      <br>Don't have an account? <span (click)="openRegister()">Register now</span>
    </p>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router : Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openRegister(){
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }
}
```

register.page.html

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar color="warning">
    <ion-title>Register</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <div class="">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="u_name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="u_email_address"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="u_password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Confirm Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="u_confirm_password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <br><br><br>
      <ion-button expand="block" class="ion-padding" color="warning" (click)="tryRegister()" [disabled]="disabledButton">Register</ion-button>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

register.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastController, LoadingController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AccessProviders } from '../providers/access-providers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  u_name          : string = "";
  u_email_address : string = "";
  u_password      : string = "";
  u_confirm_password : string = "";

  disabledButton;

  constructor(
    private router : Router,
    private toastCtrl : ToastController,
    private loadingCtrl : LoadingController,
    private alertCtrl : AlertController,
    private accsPrvds: AccessProviders
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.disabledButton = false;
  }

  async tryRegister(){
    if(this.u_name == ""){
      this.presentToast('Name is required');
    }else if(this.u_email_address == ""){
      this.presentToast('Email is required');
    }else if(this.u_password == ""){
      this.presentToast('Password is required');
    }else if(this.u_confirm_password != this.u_password){
      this.presentToast('Password are not the same');
    }else{
      this.disabledButton = true;
      const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message: 'Please wait a moment...',
      });
      loader.present();

      return new Promise(resolve =>{
        let body = {
          aksi: 'proses_register',
          u_name: this.u_name,
          u_email_address: this.u_email_address,
          u_password: this.u_password
        }

        this.accsPrvds.postData(body, 'proses_api.php').subscribe((res:any)=>{
          if(res.success==true){
            loader.dismiss();
            this.disabledButton = false;
            this.presentToast(res.msg);
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }else{
            loader.dismiss();
            this.disabledButton = false;
            this.presentToast(res.msg);
          }
        },(err)=>{
          loader.dismiss();
          this.disabledButton = false;
          this.presentAlert('Timeout');
        });
      });
    }
  }

  async presentToast(a){
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message : a,
      duration: 1500,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  async presentAlert(a){
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: a,
      backdropDismiss: false,
      buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Close',
        handler: (blah) => {
          console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          //action
        }
      }, {
          text: 'Try Again',
          handler: () => {
            this.tryRegister();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

access-providers.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators'; 

@Injectable()
export class AccessProviders {
    //url backend api json
    server: string ='http://localhost/login-register-home/api/';

    constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

    postData(body, file){
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        });
        let options = {
            headers: headers
        }

        return this.http.post(this.server + file,JSON.stringify(body), options)
        .pipe(timeout(59000))// 59 sec timeout
        .pipe(map(res => res));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about `u_email_address` not existing in **LoginPage**. Your code shows that `u_email_address` exists in `register.page.ts`, but not in `login.page.ts`, so you can access that variable from `login.page.ts`

Each template (html) can only see the variables that you declare in their corresponding components.

Comment: I have just included the login.page.ts in the question

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed the mistake in the login.page.ts